# Getting "duplicate dict key" in Ansible trying to loop through a file of variables

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible 2.9, and AWX 15

I want to use ansible to automate setting up client VPNs. Many clients have multiple encryption domains so I need to set up object-groups.

On an ASA the config looks like:

```
object-group network ClientVPN
   object-network 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
   object-network 10.2.2.0 255.255.255.0
   object-network 10.3.3.0 255.255.255.0
```

My ansible code looks like:

```
    - name: Build object group
  asa_config:
     lines:
       - "object-group network ClientVPN"

- name: Add networks
  asa_config:
     lines:
       - "network-object {{ subnet }}"
     parents:
       - object-group network ClientVPN
  loop: "{{ lookup('file','varfil2.yml',wantlist=True) }}"
```

And my var_file looks like:

```
subnet: 192.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
subnet: 192.2.2.0 255.255.255.0 
subnet: 192.3.3.0 255.255.255.0
```

The issue is that I don't know how many "subnet" a client will have and it WILL be delivered in a file. There may be 2 or 20. So I need to be able to loop thru the task and create networks.

I can't figure out how to code the playbook and the file so that I don't get the "duplicate dict key" error.

Thanks!

Comment: That's because the file format you provided is being interpreted by ansible as yaml; if you did not intend that, then you'll need to put a space in front of the `{{ lookup(` to keep ansible from auto-corecing the input. That said, I cannot reproduce your experience because [`file` lookup does not accept `wantlist=True`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/lookup/file.html#parameters) so the content always shows up as one huge blob of text, and feeding that to `loop:` just makes one item containing the text

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Do you have any suggestions on how to do what I am trying to do? I appreciate your observations about why my current code doesn't work, but that's actually secondary to getting some form of code to work. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, with that level of specificity, I'd say start by `{{ lookup('file','varfil2.yml') | regex_findall('(?m)^subnet: (.+)') }}` and then either change `- "network-object {{ subnet }}"` to be `- "network-object {{ item }}"` so it's not blatantly wrong

Comment: Hey, mdaniel: your suggestion worked. Thanks! Part of the complexity, tho, seems to be due to the input file format. I can have that changed. How should I specify the format of the "subnet" file be delivered?

Comment: Just create a list of subnets:
`subnets: ["192.1.1.0 255.255.255.0", "192.2.2.0 255.255.255.0", "192.3.3.0 255.255.255.0"]`.

Comment: Well jtyr . . . apparently I am just not that smart. When I create a list of subnets I get "RROR! variable files must contain either a dictionary of variables, or a list of dictionaries. Got: subnet = ["192.1.1.0 255.255.255.0", "192.2.2.0 255.255.255.0"] (<class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode'>)"

Comment: - name: Add networks
      asa_config:
         lines:
           - "network-object {{ item }}"
         parents:
           - object-group network newClient
      loop: "{{ lookup('file','varfil2.yml') }}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I was getting a "duplicate dict key" error was because I these lines in my playbook:

vars_file:
- subnet-vars.yaml

And I had this line in my playbook:

loop: "{{ lookup('file','subnets.txt').splitlines() }}"

As soon as I removed the "vars_file" and the line calling the subnet-vars.yaml file, the playbook processed normally, without errors.